# How to compare received string with pre-load string in forms

Tags: c#, forms

Im new to c# and so am I to forms. Im currently working with a project where I create a Host program that is suppose to receive a string (A12345) from another program. The strings I receive from the other program will appear in listbox3, and I've made a code that is supposed to compare the string I will receive with the string I added and write "Match" in listbox4 if the strings match. But the program checks for the match before I manage to send the string from the other program. how do I manage to make the program check again after I've sent the string?

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox3.Items.Equals("A12345"))
        listBox4.Items.Add("Match");
    else
        listBox4.Items.Add("No match");
}
```

please dont laugh, but I also tried this:

```
bool myBool = true;
while (myBool)
{

    if (listBox3.Items.Equals("A9999999-K999999999"))
    {
        listBox4.Items.Add("EÖ");
        myBool = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing to understand is: ListBox.Items is a collection of strings. Even if you have put a single string in that property you cannot compare Items against a single string. You need to use an index to reference a single string in the ListBox.Items collection. Second point. I can't see where you add items to the ListBox3.Items collection.

Comment: I am a bit lost, how can another profram write in you listbox?

Comment: Did you want to use `Contains` instead?

Comment: By "Forms" do you mean "Windows Forms"? If so, please correct your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use the concept **Timer** start it and check your result while made check/button to stop it.I'm taking your code as well with `Contain(obj)` method it's working well as follow,

```
string otherProgramString = "A12345";
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox3.Items.Contains(otherProgramString))
            listBox4.Items.Add("Match");
        else
            listBox4.Items.Add("No match");
    }
    void SetStringFromOtherProgram(string value)
    {
        otherProgramString = value;
    }
    private void StartTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 1;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void EndTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        timer1.Interval = 100;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

sending the string from the other app and receiving it in ur app is called an event , you need a function to handle this event which is called event handler and ur code

```
 if (listBox3.Items.Equals("A12345"))
      listBox4.Items.Add("Match");
else
      listBox4.Items.Add("No match");
```

should be inside this event handler , i could provide a code sample if u tell me who exactly u r sending the string to ur application from the other app